# Print to console as SQL executes

Tags: postgresql

When executing multiple SQL commands, such as in the [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) SQL Editor, how can I **print some strings to the console** (output pane in pgAdmin). I want to monitor execution.

```sql
UPDATE x
SET a = b 
WHERE a IS NULL
;

Print to console --> Finished x.

UPDATE y
SET a = b 
WHERE a IS NULL
;

Print to console --> Finished y.
```

My question is the same as this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21523679/642706). Or, as Craig Ringer interpreted that Question:

> Do you wish to observe SQL queries that are run by PgAdmin-III by printing them to standard error, viewed by launching PgAdmin-III on a cmd.exe interactive console?

---

I have seen remarks about `\echo 'some_text'`. But that gives me the error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
SQL state: 42601
```

Comment: `SELECT 'some text';` `\echo` of a `psql` command, you cannot use it in pgAdmin.  If you want an error-like message (like a warning or such), you can create a pl/pgsql function that emits a message of the desired level using an incoming parameter, like the one I used [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24850/6219).

Comment: Have you got any solution for this, yet? I have a very long evolution script, which I execute inside a transaction (with `ROLLBACK` for testing purposes) and I try to know the content of a table mid-way through...

Answer (score 5):

The only way I have found is through a stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION print_notice(msg text) 
  RETURNS integer AS 
$$ 
DECLARE 
BEGIN 
    RAISE NOTICE USING MESSAGE = msg;
    RETURN null;
END; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE;
```

So, executing `SELECT print_notice('Foo ' || someText || ' !');`

Will produce (for example) :

```
NOTICE:  Foo whatever !
query result with 1 row discarded.
```

I'm not sure if this can be done without the `SELECT` and the `query ... row discarded` message. But it works.