# How to print to console in SQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using `PostgreSQL` And I want to print a message to the console.

If I use `plpythonu` I use `plpy.notice`
If I use `plpgsql` I use `raise notice`

but how do I print when the function is pure `SQL`?
using `SELECT 'string'` isn't helping me as it print the string in a column and if the message is located in the middle of the code it doesn't show it.
I want something like `raise notice` / `plpy.notice` for `SQL`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A()
  RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$ 
                how do i print 'hello world' here?
 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
```

if it was a plpgsql I would do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION A()
  RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$ 
        Raise Notice 'hello world'
 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I'm looking for the equivalent in  `LANGUAGE SQL`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693259/need-to-printing-postgresql-database-console 
check this out.

Comment: doesn't help me. the function there is in plpgsql. for plpgsql  you can do Raise Notice. I want the equivalent command for SQL function.

Comment: There is  no equivalent top `raise`in plain SQL

Comment: Cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260497/how-to-print-to-console-in-sql

Comment: Maybe a `SELECT 'hello world'`?  Other than that, I used a solution for something else here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24850/6219

Answer (score 19):

With `psql` you could `\echo text` (or `\qecho` if using `\o`), for example executing with `psql -f` a file with contents:

```
select 'Straight';
\echo BETWEEN
select 'the lines.';
```

outputs:

```
 ?column? 
----------
 Straight
(1 row)

BETWEEN
  ?column?  
------------
 the lines.
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 9):

Why not just call the plpgsql function that raises a notice, from inside the SQL function?

According to the doc:

> SQL functions execute an arbitrary list of SQL statements, returning
>   the result of the last query in the list

So a SELECT statement can be inserted at the beginning without changing the result.

```
create function print(text) returns void as 
$$ begin raise notice '%', $1; end 
$$ language plpgsql; 

create function whatever(int) returns int as $$
  select print('foobar');
  select $1;
 $$ language sql;

select whatever(3);
NOTICE:  foobar
CONTEXT:  SQL function "whatever" statement 1
 whatever 
----------
        3
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can execute bash commands from psql. For example:

```
\! echo "HERE YOUR DEBUG MSG!"
select * from your_table;
```

Comment: While this is true, you cannot do this from inside a SQL function.